# Format notifications send from Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I have created a Notification Hub in Azure. I try to send a notification to my Android App using this programme (c#):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var myHub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("my connection string", "My hub name");

  string messageJson = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"The message\", \"title\": \"A title\"}}";

  myHub.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(messageJson);

  Console.WriteLine("Done! Press enter to continue");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The notification arrives at my Android phone, but no matter how I format the Json message, the notification hub changes the title to "FCM Message".

[Image showing the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efwi9.png)

Do you have any input to the correct way to send notifications from Azure Notification Hub?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, so it may only help others who end up here, but I was having the exact same issue as you and got it figured out. In this example, "action" is a custom data field that I'm pulling out once it gets to the device, and the title and message/body are correctly displayed.

```
{
    "data": {
        "action": "Movement"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "This is a title",
        "body": "test message"
    }
}
```

Microsoft's example was just really terrible and confused the issue.